# Deployment on heroku crashing

Tags: heroku, mern

I am deploying my MERN application to Heroku. The build is successful but when I open my application the web page shows application error. I checked logs but couldn't understand much from that.

This is my first deployment of an MERN application, so please guide me. Thankyou.

**These are the logs**

[image]

[image]

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/database');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Connect Database
connectDB();

// Init Middleware
app.use(express.json({extended: false}));

// Defining Routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users'));
app.use('/api/contacts', require('./routes/contacts'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'));

// Serve static assets in production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Set static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    })
}

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**server's package.json**

```
{
  "name": "contact-keeper",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Contact Manager App",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "clientinstall": "npm install --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.18.3"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.12.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: Its appears that ./config/database is not loaded. Could you validate if exist in heroku? Sometimes files like this is ignored in .gitignore

Comment: No database.js is not in .gitignore file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: I see `mongoURI is not defined` in your log. Try to validate if your database config are ok

Comment: Thanks man for guiding me towards the bug. The error was my mongoURI was in gitignore. I removed it from gitignore and now web page is opening. Thankyou v. Much!